# gremlin-javascript non-bytecode script submission timing out on local gremlin-server

Tags: node.js, gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm running a local instance of gremlin-server. I'm using the included `gremlin-server.yaml` configuration file. I am able to access the server via gremlin console and have confirmed it is functioning as intended.

However, when I attempt to do something like this

```
const client = new Gremlin.driver.Client("ws:// endpoint", {
  traversalsource: "g",
});


client.submit(
      "g.addV(label).property('id', id).property('firstName', firstName).property('age', age).property('userid', userid)",
      {
        label: "person",
        id: "thomas",
        firstName: "Thomas",
        age: 44,
        userid: 1
      }
    )
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log("Result: %s\n", JSON.stringify(result));
    });
```

I receive no answer and it's like the program hangs. I've thrown a catch statement in there as well, just sharing this as an example.

Comment: have you examined the server console output for errors?

Comment: @stephenmallette yes I did - there are no errors and no changes to it.

Comment: do other sorts of traversals work? what if you didn't even bother with a traversal and just sent a simple "1+1"?